# How to insert data into CreateAPIVIew's response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I currently have the following code which, upon creating an object, returns the serialization of the item.

```
class Item(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, default=uuid1)
    puid = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)


class ServerCreateView(CreateAPIView):

    def perform_create(self, serializer):

        # Create
        instance = serializer.save()

        # Updates its previous uid
        puid = self.model_class.objects\
            .values_list('uid', flat=True)\
            .filter(pk__lt=instance.pk)\
            .order_by('-pk')[:1][0]

        self.model_class.objects
            .filter(pk=instance.pk)\
            .update(puid=puid, sdtc=datetime.now())
```

I need to be able to return its puid though and it isn't calculated until after the model is saved. I know I can opt to go `instance = serializer.save(puid={puid})` which will include its puid in the reponse however this leaves room for a race condition in the event that another Item is saved in between the time the puid is retrieved and the item itself is saved and I also need to prevent that. Is there any way to do this without opening my data up to risk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, write a serializer class, that override create function on this.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= mymodel
        fields=(add your desire fields)
    def create(self, validated_data):
        #do some process
        mymodel_obj=mymodel.objects.create()
        return mymodel_obj
```